# What is the best way to synchronize database via internet? MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, data-synchronization

I want to build a desktop application somewhat like a POS. The user can enter data to it and save the data to a local database instead of accessing a remote database in the server. The reason I want to do this is to reduce the traffic and make my application more responsive since it will make less overhead of accessing a remote database.

I want to build at least 5 client of this desktop application and each of them has a local database. Along with these clients, I will setup a server database which I will use for reports or for online access that displays all the status and data of all my clients.

For example, a specific user uses the client machine, all of his data will be stored in the local database before it can be transported to the server database for synchronization. I would seem like this system doesn't give a real time data update to the server but this is what I need. Since the server database is only used for reporting purposes, there is no information in the server that is manipulated by a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may looking for [jumpmind](http://www.jumpmind.com/) product called SymmetricDS. It Sync data from branch offices with a central office, sharing data with all offices and syncing subsets of data with specific offices.